Using drush PolicyCommands.php
Currently on drush v12.5.2.0 and I am using drush sql:sync to sync my local with the remote db. I want to ensure I do not enter @prod for the target.
I realized I could use drush policy to validate [https://www.drush.org/12.x/examples/PolicyCommands.php/][1]
I have the below file in my project/drush/Commands
<?php

namespace Drush\Commands;

use Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandData;
use Drush\Commands\DrushCommands;


class PolicyCommands extends DrushCommands {
  /**
   * Prevent catastrophic braino.
   *
   * @throws \Exception
   */
  #[CLI\Hook(type: HookManager::ARGUMENT_VALIDATOR, target: SqlSyncCommands::SYNC)]
  public function sqlSyncValidate(CommandData $commandData) {
    if ($commandData->input()->getArgument('target') == '@prod') {
      throw new \Exception(dt('Per !file, you may never overwrite the production database.', ['!file' => __FILE__]));
    }
  }

}

I cleared the drush cache using drush cc drush as well.
#Load this commandfile using the --include option - e.g. `drush --include=/path/to/drush/examples .
I ran drush --include=~/project/drush/Commands but still no luck.
Kind of a newbie so am I missing something? If I still give drush sql:sync @self @prod it does not throw any Exception..

Is there a reason you went with the Drush\Commands\PolicyCommands namespace rather than Drush\Commands? I don't know if that's the only problem here, but it looks wrong. In addition have you execute Drush in debug/verbose mode for more information?

Another sample to compare with: https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project/blob/10.x/drush/Commands/PolicyCommands.php

I don't know if they've changed it, but in the past I was not able to use sql:sync to remote aliases.

@monalisa thank you for pointing that out. I actually tried with Drush\Commands at first but still couldn't make it work. I have edited the question's code.

@monalisa I checked verbose output it seems like the function is not getting executed. How do I add this file to the drush configuration? I have added this path to drush.yml under drush:paths:include

This works just fine. drush sql:sync @self @prod will first ask a question if we want to destroy the live database and replace it with our local and our validation function is executed only if we enter YES. I was under the impression that it runs before the interactive question. Just learned this.
